# Creating 100 variables

Tags: c#, loops, variables, range, sbyte

So I created an array with 100 variables using `Enumerable.Range`. The data type is limited to `Int32`.

### Problem

- How can I create the same array with `SByte`?
- Am I right in thinking I would need to use a loop to create and index the variables?

I have looked around online and most results touch on declaring counting variables for the loop but not using a loop to declare variables

Comment: _"So I created an array with 100 variables using enumerable range [...] How can I create the same array with sByte?"_ Well... exactly the same way, but change `int` to `sbyte`.

Comment: You wouldn't use a loop to declare variables. You can use a loop to add elements to an array. Maybe the mix-up in terminology is causing problems with your searching?

Comment: `Enumerable.Range(1, 100).Select(n => (sbyte)n).ToArray()`. But this does not create 100 *variables*, but an array of 100 *values*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just cast them:

```
SByte[] array = Enumerable.Range(0, 100).Select(i => (SByte) i).ToArray();
```

note that `SByte` is not cls compliant, you might want to use `short` instead.